# Calculating and Finding the explicit function of an improper integral

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm not sure what my professor means by "define a function of t,M" and I don't know how to calculate this integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the integral in (a), do integration by parts, with $u=2x^2,dv=e^{-2x}$, then do integration by parts again. That gives you the indefinite integral, so find the definite integral from that.

For the second part, your professor means to let

$$M(t)=\int_0^\infty 2e^{tx}\cdot e^{-2x}\,dx$$

which is a function in $t$ since $x$ is a dummy variable and disappears. Then find a simpler, closed formula for $M(t)$.

That is pretty easy, since $t$ is a constant in the integration, and you just combine the integrand into $2e^{(t-2)x}$. Again, treat $(t-2)$ as a constant.

Here are the details:

$$\begin{align}
M(t) &= \int_0^\infty 2e^{tx}\cdot e^{-2x}\,dx \\
 &= \int_0^\infty 2e^{tx-2x}\,dx \\
 &= \int_0^\infty 2e^{(t-2)x}\,dx \\
 &= \left.\frac{2}{t-2}e^{(t-2)x}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
 &= \frac{2}{t-2}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{(t-2)x}-e^{(t-2)0}\right) \\
 &= \frac{2}{t-2}(0-1) \quad\text{for $t<2$}\\
 &= \frac{2}{2-t} \quad\text{for $t<2$}
\end{align}
$$

That limit is true if $t<2$: the limit, hence the integral, is undefined for $t\ge 2$.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but where does t-2 come from? Is this a result of t, treated as a constant? How would I then be able to take a first and second derivative of such a function?

Comment: @user151876: $2e^{tx}\cdot e^{-2x}=2e^{tx+-2x}=2e^{(t-2)x}$. That is true whether or not $t$ is treated as a constant. But finding $\int_0^\infty 2e^{(t-2)x}\,dx$ is easily done treating $t-2$ as a constant, since $\int e^{cx}\,dx=\frac 1c e^{cx}$ when $c$ is a constant. When you have found a simple expression for $M(t)$ you will be able to take derivatives of that expression.

Comment: If I solve the integral with t-2 as a constant and compute the boundaries, I get infinity as the solution. Is that the answer for part b or are they looking for something else? Edit: I actually get infinity - 1/(t-2) as my solution

Comment: @user151876: See the additions to my answer. Note that your answer is correct if $t>2$, thus the function $M(t)$ is undefined there, as well as at $t=2$.